# Using handler to open a form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm ultra noob when it comes to C# so bear with me.

I'm creating a menu at runtime. It can goes from one to N options and every one of them has a callback function (showing a form or calling other routine). I have this app in VB but I'm doing it again using C# (-learn something new-). There I use MethodInvoker and AddressOf.

Steps:

Add a new menu item

```
mg.AddItem("Users", UserForm.ShowList);
```

Then, add its callback

```
...
newMenuOption.Click += option_click; 
menu.Items.Add(newMenuOption);
```

On option_click method I invoke the item's callback that it is stored.

```
Invoke((Item)sender).Tag).m_MenuCallback);
```

I'm done with it.

First mg.AddItem gives error if UserForm.ShowList is not static. (If so, it works but I can't do anything besides showing a MessageBox and such).

I've tried with MethodInvoker, EventArgs, object ...

My scenario is filling a Panorama (telerik control) with Tiles (Menu Item) at runtime (they change according the user logged in). So every Tile opens a new form or perform a diferent task. I got this (not the exact example) working on VB but C# is giving me a hard time.

PS:

UserForm.ShowList will populate a grid with users and show the form. Can't do either of that while ShowList is a static method.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be making an instance of your UserForm(*With visual basic you can access a default instance of the form, this was left in for VB6 compatability reasons*).

```
UserForm usf = new UserForm();
```

then add it like

```
mg.AddItem("Users", usf.ShowList);
```